# Changing values of pivot table cache without changing source data

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Is it possible to change a value in pivot table cache without changing it in source data (be it either an Excel sheet or external source)?

Is it possible to work with a cache itself i.e. by working with it like an array?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that's possible. About the best you could do is to create a new cache, and change the PivotTable data source. Here's how that looks:

```
 pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= SomeAddress)
```